# PHP - Displaying Blog Menu by Date

Tags: php, mysql, database, blogs, date

I have created a function to display the dates and the count of posts within those dates to be used as my blog menu, however it only partially works, any help with this would be appreciated.

Function being called:

```
function displayBlogMenu()
{
    blogDBSelect();
    $sql = "SELECT datePosted FROM blog_entries";
    $results = mysql_query($sql);           
    while($post = mysql_fetch_array($results))
    {
        $startDate = date('Y-m-01', strtotime($post['datePosted']));
        $endDate = date('Y-m-01',  strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($post['datePosted'])));  
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM blog_entries WHERE datePosted >= '$startDate' AND datePosted < '$endDate'";
        $results2 = mysql_query($sql2); 
        $count = mysql_num_rows($results2);
    }                                   
    echo '<a href="">'.date('F, Y', strtotime($startDate)).' ('.$count.' Posts)</a><br>';
}
```

I want the function to return the date as links such as:

```
June, 2011 (10 Posts)
July, 2011 (2 Posts)
```

Comment: I guess, a simple WHERE date ='?' condition on your query would do. And then count the fetched rows.

Comment: I already have a where date = condition. If there are 10 posts for example in a month, I only want the echo to be posted once, the count already works.

Comment: what do you mean with "I only want the echo to be posted once.. " ?

Comment: Well I don't want the echo in the code to repeat for every post in a month, if there are two posts I don't want the menu to echo twice, just the count to increment.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you can do that by one single query

```
SELECT Date_format(dateposted, '%M, %Y'), 
       COUNT(*) AS cc 
FROM   blog_entries 
GROUP  BY YEAR(dateposted), 
          MONTH(dateposted) 
ORDER  BY COUNT(*) DESC, 
          dateposted DESC
```